# How do I modify this Fibonacci Sequence Problem?

Tags: python, sequence, fibonacci

I am trying to figure out how I can modify the code below to help solve the question given. However, instead of only being able to take 1 or 2 steps at a time, I want to make it so I can also take 3 steps.

You have a ladder of N steps (rungs). You can go up the  ladder by taking either 1 step or two steps at a time, in any combination. How many different routes are there (combinations of 1 steps or 2 steps) to make it up the ladder?

Here is some code that I'm trying to modify:

```
def countP(n):
    if (n == 1 or n == 2):
        return n

    return countP(n-1) + countP(n-2)
```

I've already tried this so far and I am not getting the correct answer:

```
def countP(n):
    if (n == 1 or n == 2 or n == 3):
        return n

    return countP(n-1) + countP(n-2) + countP(n-3)
```

Any help of guidance would be of great help! Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is returning `n`.  While it's true that there will be 1 way to take 1 step (i.e. take 1 step of 1 length), and 2 ways to take 2 steps (2 steps of 1 or 1 step of 2), this pattern doesn't persist for 3 steps.  How many ways are there to take 3 steps?  That's what you should return if `n == 3`.

Comment: Sounds like a rewording of a change making problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base case in the recursion for `n = 3` is wrong.
For `n = 3`, the correct answer should be `4`, but you are returning `3`.
I suggest you to simplify the base case by using the following observations:

1. Utmost base case is when `n <= 1` i.e when we have only one stair or no stair, hence the only way to climb is taking a step of 1 unit or 0 unit. Hence, number of ways is `countP(0) = 1` and `countP(1) = 1`.
2. What happens when `n > 1` ?  
   Well, we have three options to take for first step - we can take `m` units (1 unit, 2 units or 3 units step) as first step provided `m <= n`.
   If we can take 1 unit step as first step, we can reduce the sub-problem from `countP(n)` to `countP(n-1)`.
   If we can take 2 units step as first step, we can reduce the sub-problem from `countP(n)` to `countP(n-2)`.
   If we can take 3 units step as first step, we can reduce the sub-problem from `countP(n)` to `countP(n-3)`.
   So, our final count will be : `countP(n - m)` for all `m <= n`

Code will be as follows:

```
def countP(n):
    if (n == 0 or n == 1):
        return 1

    count = 0
    for m in [1, 2, 3]:
        if m <= n:
            count += countP(n - m)

    return count
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution!

Answer (score 0):

The line `return n` is correct for the first problem but not the second. Keep in mind that the result is supposed to be the number of possible routes you can take.

If you can take either one or two steps at a time, then when you have one rung left, there is only one thing to do: take one step. If you have two rungs left, you have two options: either take two steps, or take one step (one rung), then another (the second rung). So, somewhat by coindicence, for this version of the problem the number of routes in the base case happens to equal the number of rungs left.

If you can take either one, two or three steps at a time, then the number of routes when you have three rungs remaining is not three; there are more than three options. You will have to count how many options there are, and return that in the case where `n == 3`.